# How to get the data that contain in comma separated values column in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to pass one clm_id and want the data from table which contain that clm_id
like i pass 2012(clm_id) and want output data which contain 2012 in comma sperated value also.

What i want is that in 1st table there is clm_id which is repeated i want the data which id having repeated value including in comma separated value.

like

```
id     clm_id
1       2011,2012
2       2012,2013
3       2012
```

output want :

```
id    clm_id
1      2012
2      2012 
3      2012
```

like id(1,2,3) that contain 2012 clm_id

i have query like 
`SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE ( clm_id in ('2012'))` but not get value from comma separated value

Comment: You need to elaborate your question.Provide more examples, because now your question doesn't make any sense, not to me at least.. If you post what you've tried so far we might be able to understand what you are trying to acheive

Comment: Your database design is wrong. You would be better off normalizing your database design or you will keep running into troubles forever

Comment: @GuidoG this is just an example

Comment: Still, you have more than one value in a single column. that is very bad practice. You should change the design of your database to avoid this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: what version of sql server are you using ? From version 2016 you can use the STRING_SPLIT function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
    declare @YourTable TABLE (id int,clm_id varchar(50))

    INSERT @YourTable SELECT 1,'2011,2012'
    INSERT @YourTable SELECT 2,'2012,2013'
    INSERT @YourTable SELECT 3,'2012'

    declare @SearchYear char(4)='2012' -- input search value

    SELECT 
    id 
    ,@SearchYear AS [clm_id]
    FROM @YourTable
    WHERE
    CHARINDEX(@SearchYear,clm_id,0)>0
    ORDER BY id
```

result :

```
id  clm_id
1   2012
2   2012
3   2012
```

Comment: but now how to convert this into Linq query ?

Comment: What .net language are you using ? VB or C# ?

Comment: in C# @noldy Nayoan

Comment: I wanted to help, but come to think of it, this is a little bit off topic. I think it's better if you submit new post for your linq question. I would try to answer your new post.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way using like (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and case (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
WITH tmp (id, clm_id) AS
  (
  SELECT 1, '2011,2012'
  UNION
  SELECT 2, '2012,2013'
  UNION
  SELECT 3, '2012'
  )

SELECT 
tmp.id,
CASE
WHEN  tmp.clm_id LIKE '%2012%'
    THEN '2012'
ELSE ''
END AS clm_id
 FROM tmp
```

If you have SQL server 2016 or later you can use a nifty new function:

```
  SELECT 
    id, cs.value       
   FROM tmp CROSS APPLY
   STRING_SPLIT(tmp.clm_id,',') cs
   WHERE cs.value='2012'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) Query will work. [Check here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f304/1)

```
select id, clm_id from test where clm_id like '%2012%'
```

The above will returns the filtered query and if you want just your search param as your select column, why can't you make it simple?

```
select id, '2012' from test where clm_id like '%2012%'
```

Anyhow, as GuidoG suggested you need to change your schema a bit.

Comment: This does not accomplish what the OP has asked for

Comment: @GuidoG, I think it is

Comment: Run your query and compare your output with the desired output of the OP

Comment: But not using Like

Comment: @KajalSawant, Could you re-phrase your question for your exact requirements?

Answer (score 0):

String_Split is newest built-in function provided for such tasks

```
select
    id, t.[value] as clm_id
from CLM
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(clm_id,',') as t
where [value] = '2012'
```

Comment: your query produces output as :                                                                     
               `id clm_id
  1 2011
  1 2012
  2 2012
  2 2013
  3 2012`

Comment: your query produces output as :  <br/>                                                                   
               `id clm_id <br/>
  1 2011 <br/>
  1 2012 <br/>
  2 2012 <br/>
  2 2013 <br/>
  3 2012` <br/>

Comment: Sorry your query is correct, there was a typo when I tested it. Cheers..